# Does behavior in JavaBean constructor slow deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, constructor

I have a bean which initializes a unique id in its constructor because there is no reason to ask the caller to do so when the object can simply do it itself.

I plan on having the object be serializable. The old id should survive even if a new one is set from the empty constructor as `set..()` will be called afterwards.

But in this situation it seems as though `UUID.randomUUID()` will get called on every deserialization even though it will no longer necessary after the initial construction.

The object is being passed over the network and will be deserialized at each stop along the way because the object holds state as to where it should be routed next. Is each stop going to waste time generating a new id only to have it overwritten? Should I construct my bean differently given my use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors of serializable classes are not called on deserialization.